A query about the 1st and 2nd publications of the Rabbinic Bible printed by Daniel Bomberg, re. the Masoretic Text and the Septuagint
An article in the booklet quoted from below causes me to wonder if this, the preferred text of religious Jews and Hebrew Christians, is at any risk of textual changes being made to it, which would not be good changes. The article in question states that Bomberg:

“…produced the first Rabbinic Bible in 1517. This was the first to
present a complete Masorah, and in time it became the ‘textus
receptus’ of the Old Testament. (Endnote: It was known in Hebrew as
the Mikraot Gedelot.) …[one] edition the Ginsburg 1894/1998 was used
as the basis for the Old Testament for many Reformation-era
translations such as the English Authorised Version and the Dutch
Statenvertaling. (Endnote: During the Reformation period it was used
by R.I. Estienne (also known in Latin as Robertus Stephanus, 1503 –
1559 in his Hebrew Bible of 1544-1546.)” Quarterly Record TBS, Issue
No. 649 October-December 2024, pp. 4-6

Bomberg then produced the second edition in 1524, making this year of 2024 the 500th anniversary of the Second Rabbinic Bible. However, my concern arises due to this paragraph:

“Sadly, in our own day the Hebrew Masoretic text preserved for us by
Divine providence is undermined by those who wish to add text outside
of the Masoretic editions. The majority of these look to ancient
translations in other languages.” (Ibid. p.5)

My question is: Does this mean that the Septuagint (Greek) translation of the Hebrew scriptures is not entirely reliable?

I don't see how I can answer this... or are you just asking which one is possibly the most historically valid? Because for example the Orthodox Church uses the Septuagint (LXX) for the old testament. And the controversy of "this translation changed something" is a very common accusation around editions of the Bible. What of the Peshitta? etc...

It is generally recognised (in TR circles) that LXX should not be relied on in contradiction to the Masoretic. I hope someone will be able to give a full and substantiated answer in regard to this. Up-voted +1.
